# What does the purple progress bar mean for electric drills?

Tags: factorio

With the .15 release of Factorio, nuclear power has been added.  With this, came uranium ore.  I just began harvesting some uranium with my electric drill, and noticed that there is a purple progress bar:

[image: Purple progress bar]

<s>On electric mining drills that aren't working on uranium, this bar isn't here.</s>  I don't think it has to do with the speed modules that are inserted either (the bar doesn't seem to move any differently with or without them). What does it indicate?

This is game version 0.15.5 if that helps.

Comment: In the previous version it represented "increased output upgrade" - when the bar made it to the end, you'd get one free product.  Maybe it's due to those upgrades?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I don't think it has to do with the speed modules upgrades.  I've edited that into my post. I don't see any difference in progress with the purple bar with the modules inserted. Just the green bar moves faster as expected.

Comment: It's for the productivity module, not the speed module.

Comment: Do you have any of the new mining productivity upgrades? That's my first suspicion, but you said it's not on other electric drills.

Comment: @mmatthews I haven't built any other modules yet besides the speed ones.  When I play the game next, I'm going to experiment with other modules and see what happens.  Based off the rest of the comments, it looks like the productivity module may do something.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, there is also a research that increases mining productivity.

Comment: @mmatthews I think you're on to something.  I just checked my game, and all the drills do have that purple bar.  I guess I just didn't notice until I placed the one for uranium.  If you could formulate your thoughts into an answer - that be great! I'm not sure how the productivity bonus works exactly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Version 0.15 introduced a new line of upgrades, called Mining Productivity.  Researching these upgrades have a similar effect to using Productivity Modules, in that each miner will have a purple bar that slowly fills up, producing an additional ore when it fills up.

I haven't tested to see if burner drills receive the upgrade as well, but all electric drills are affected.

Comment: And pumpjacks also get this bonus.

Comment: Same for assembly machines (1 and 2 at least). I've seen this myself.